# Qt - trying to align two GroupBoxes in a layout

Tags: c++, qt, layout

A part of my form contains `QGroupBox` (`Status Box`) with 4 child `QGroupBox`es arranged in a grid layout (2x2). Two bottom `QGroupBox`es (`Widget 1 Box` and `Widget 2 Box`) contain widgets of fixed size (with set `minimumSize` and `maximumSize`) so they're non-resizable at all in both directions. Because of that rigid size constraints top row of `QGroupBox`es (`Summary Box` and `Helper Box`) can only be resized in vertical direction.

And here comes the troublesome part. Top-left `QGroupBox` (`Summary Box`) have grid layout 5x3 while top-right (`Helper Box`) have vertical layout with 6 rows. If I have naive widget placement as shown on picture 1 Qt is enlarging vertical size of both labels in top row to make height of both `QGroupBox`es equal (see red arrows on picture 1).

[image: Picture 1 - naive widget placement]

This is definitely that I don't want so I've added vertical spacer to the bottom of `Summary Box` and from the first glance it worked (picture 2). But only from the first glance... What you see is the minimum height of my whole form and the bottom side of spacer and last `QCheckBox` in the `Helper Box` seems to be aligned.

[image: Picture 2 - vertical spacer added]

If I'm expanding my form vertically this spacer grows a bit and that causes the increase of height of both top `QGroupBox`es. As a result spacing between `QCheckBox`es increases too and we can also see that top and bottom spacing are unequal for the top-right box (see red arrows on picture 3).

[image]

I've tried to play with `sizeType` for my vertical spacer. If I set it to `Minimum` or `MinimumExpanding` then the spacer doesn't grow on resize (and doesn't shrink, too) but it appears to be expanded to the size as on picture 3 (corrupting spacings between `QCheckBox`es too). If I set it to `Maximum`, `Preferred` or `Expanding` then I observe the same behavior as described above for picture 3.

What is the proper way to achieve alignment for two `QGroupBox`es in a row of grid without affecting spacing between elements (e. g. in that case make vertical spacer to fit only single row of grid layout and never expand/shrink)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items will be aligned if both `QGroupBox`es have same count of children and each row have at least one child with `Expanding` vertical policy. Instead of spacer use `QWidget`

I removed unrelated widgets and reduces number of rows to 4 for demonstration purposes (less xml).

[image: design]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>467</width>
    <height>314</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
     <property name="title">
      <string>GroupBox</string>
     </property>
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Expanding">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>TextLabel</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="3" column="2">
       <widget class="QWidget" name="dummy" native="true">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Expanding">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="0" colspan="2">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Expanding">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>TextLabel</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="2">
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit"/>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="2">
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_4">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_5">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Expanding">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>TextLabel</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_2">
     <property name="title">
      <string>GroupBox</string>
     </property>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Expanding">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>CheckBox</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_4">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Expanding">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>CheckBox</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_5">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Expanding">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>CheckBox</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_6">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Expanding">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>CheckBox</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, replacing spacer with QWidget worked fine! Also I've discovered that there is no need to set Expanding policy for all rows - it works just with adding dummy QWidget